# React Native maps - rendering a draggable (re-sizable) circle

Tags: geometry, react-native-maps

I was wondering how I can possibly render a circle onto a MapView that is draggable, in that you drag the outer perimeter of the circle and the radius changes depending on the drag direction. And then crucially, being able to capture this radius in meters.

I do not know how to even begin with this, but I can show you how I am rendering my circle component. It renders perfectly and moves around with me as I move.

```
<MapView.Circle
    key = { (userPosition.longitude + userPosition.latitude).toString() }
    center = { userPosition }
    radius = { this.props.circleRadius }
    strokeWidth = { 1 }
    strokeColor = { '#1a66ff' }
    fillColor = { 'rgba(230,238,255,0.5)' }
    onRegionChangeComplete = { this.onRegionChangeComplete.bind(this) }
/>
```

Is there a property of MapView.Circle that I am not aware of? Or do I have to build my own custom component for this?

Surely this is possible?

Answer (score 0):

for anyone looking for a custom solution, you can do something similar to this:

```
<Marker 
    coordinate={coord}                        
    fillColor={'rgba(101,75,169,0.5)'}
    draggable
    onDragEnd={(e) => {}}
    onPress={(e) => {}}
>
    <View
        style={{
            width: 20,
            height: 20,
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(101,75,169,0.75)',
            borderRadius: 10,
            borderColor: 'black',
            borderWidth: 1
        }}
    />
</Marker
```